# Split a string by a character

Tags: c#, .net

I have this string here:

```
String FileNameOrginal = "lighthouse-126.jpg";
```

and I am trying to split the string into 2, seperating it with "-"

I have tried the following, but I get a syntax error on the Spilt:

```
String FileNameOrginal = drProduct["productHTML"].ToString();
string[] strDataArray = FileNameOrginal.Split("-");
```

Please Help, I do not understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need a character instead of string:

```
string[] strDataArray = FileNameOrginal.Split('-');
```

Comment: Agreed, note the use of single quotes instead of double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is that you need an array for an input, like this:

```
string[] strDataArray = FileNameOrginal.Split(
    new string[] { "-" },
    StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: While this is true, for his use case, I think using a character is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
string[] strDataArray = FileNameOrginal.Split("-");
```

Try

```
string[] strDataArray = FileNameOrginal.Split('-');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  string FileNameOrginal = "lighthouse-126.jpg";
        string file1 = FileNameOrginal.Split('-')[0];
        string file2 = FileNameOrginal.Split('-')[1];
```